# How can I set the maximum number of characters per column using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

While using SQL Server Management Studio, I generally do:

```
Query->Query Options->Advanced->SET NOCOUNT
Query->Query Options->Text->Enter 8000 in the lower right box
```

Can someone please tell me if there is anyway I could do this using `sqlcmd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these [switches for sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) that affect width etc

- -w
- -Y
- -y

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are trying to do, but to set data type in the column for example to varchar with maximum length 30:

```
sqlcmd -E -d dbname -Q "ALTER TABLE table_name
                          ALTER COLUMN column_name varchar(30) NOT NULL"
```

For database named 'dbname' on your local machine.